# Recoring Audio using bluetooth headset in GingerBread

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, audiorecord

In my application i use [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) API for recording. My application has an option to connect and record via Bluetooth device.

My app records and playback audio via Bluetooth headset successfully in devices with android 4.0 and later , while in android 2.3 the audio can be played but can't record audio via Bluetooth input.

does gingerbread support recording audio via Bluetooth headset?

This is the code that i use to set bluetooth device:

```
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
        mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
        mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

Comment: It does as far as I can recall. How are you telling Android that you want to use the accessory's mic rather than the internal mic?

Comment: @Michael I created the AudioRecord instance by setting the audio source as AudioSource.MIC

Comment: You should also call the AudioManager's `setBluetoothScoOn` method.

Comment: @Michael yes, i am calling it already. i have updated the question with the code.